# Human based genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Where can I find an implementation of Human Based Genetic algorithm (HBGA) ?
I did search but there were not any good results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for something really specific. HBGA is just a concept: delegating decisions to a human. There are several GA frameworks out there, and I guess you could implement a GA for your specific problem and then override the desired operators to accept human input.

You can try:
http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/0_6rc1

Comment: Thank you very much George
Your answer was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Actually if I understand you correctly, you want Human Input in place of the computer for selection?
In that case this may be of interest:

http://endlessforms.com/